# How to round values in Pyomo

Tags: pyomo

I have a variable in Pyomo called `model.variable_objectiveCosts` and I would like to print this value to a file. Basically it works. But when I would like to divide the value by 100 and then round to 2 decimal digits, I get an error when using the following code  `"%.2f" %   model.variable_objectiveCosts/100`

The error message is

```
"TypeError: Implicit conversion of Pyomo NumericValue type `variable_objectiveCosts' to a float is
disabled. This error is often the result of using Pyomo components as
arguments to one of the Python built-in math module functions when
defining expressions. Avoid this error by using Pyomo-provided math
functions."
```

Now it tells me to use the Pyomo-provided math functions. However, I could not find a round function in Pyomo. Do you know how I can still round the result to 2 digits?

Here is a part of my code:

```
# Imports
import pyomo.environ as pyo
import pandas as pd
from pyomo.util.infeasible import log_infeasible_constraints
from pyomo.opt import SolverStatus, TerminationCondition
import sys

#Check if the problem is solved or infeasible
if (solution.solver.status == SolverStatus.ok) and (solution.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.optimal):
        # Do something when the solution in optimal and feasible
        print("Result Status: Optimal")
        #Create pandas dataframe for displaying the results
        outputVariables_list = [model.variable_heatGenerationCoefficient_SpaceHeating, model.variable_heatGenerationCoefficient_DHW, model.variable_help_OnlyOneStorage, model.variable_temperatureBufferStorage, model.variable_usableVolumeDHWTank, model.variable_surplusPowerTotal, model.variable_surplusPowerPositivePart, model.variable_surplusPowerNegativePart, model.variable_help_isSurplusPowerPositive, model.variable_electricalPowerTotal, model.variable_RESGenerationTotal, model.variable_pvGeneration, model.variable_costsPerTimeSlotPositivePart, model.variable_revenuePerTimeSlotPositivePart, model.variable_currentChargingPowerEV, model.variable_energyLevelEV, model.variable_SOC_EV, model.param_heatDemand_In_W, model.param_DHWDemand_In_W, model.param_electricalDemand_In_W, model.param_pvGenerationNominal, model.param_outSideTemperature_In_C, model.param_windAssignedNominal, model.param_electricityPrice_In_Cents, model.param_availabilityPerTimeSlotOfEV, model.param_energyConsumptionEV, model.param_COPHeatPump_SpaceHeating, model.param_COPHeatPump_DHW, model.param_BigM_Surplus_Positive, model.param_BigM_Surplus_Negative, model.param_BigM_Costs_Positive, model.param_BigM_Costs_Negative, model.variable_objectiveMaximumLoad, model.variable_objectiveSurplusEnergy ,model.variable_objectiveCosts, model.objective_combined_general, model.set_timeslots]
        optimal_values_list = [[pyo.value(model_item[key]) for key in model_item] for model_item in outputVariables_list] 
        results = pd.DataFrame(optimal_values_list)
        results= results.T
        results = results.rename(columns = {0:'variable_heatGenerationCoefficient_SpaceHeating', 1:'variable_heatGenerationCoefficient_DHW', 2:'variable_help_OnlyOneStorage', 3:'variable_temperatureBufferStorage', 4:'variable_usableVolumeDHWTank', 5:'variable_surplusPowerTotal', 6:'variable_surplusPowerPositivePart', 7:'variable_surplusPowerNegativePart', 8:'variable_help_isSurplusPowerPositive', 9:'variable_electricalPowerTotal', 10:'variable_RESGenerationTotal', 11:'variable_pvGeneration', 12:'variable_costsPerTimeSlot', 13:'variable_revenuePerTimeSlot', 14:'variable_currentChargingPowerEV', 15:'variable_energyLevelEV', 16:'variable_SOC_EV', 17:'param_heatDemand_In_W', 18:'param_DHWDemand_In_W', 19:'param_electricalDemand_In_W', 20:'param_pvGenerationNominal', 21:'param_outSideTemperature_In_C', 22:'param_windAssignedNominal', 23:'param_electricityPrice_In_Cents', 24:'param_availabilityPerTimeSlotOfEV', 25:'param_energyConsumptionEV', 26:'param_COPHeatPump_SpaceHeating', 27:'param_COPHeatPump_DHW', 28:'param_BigM_Surplus_Positive', 29:'param_BigM_Surplus_Negative', 30:'param_BigM_Costs_Positive', 31:'param_BigM_Costs_Negative', 32:'variable_objectiveMaximumLoad_kW', 33:'variable_objectiveSurplusEnergy_kWH', 34:'variable_objectiveCosts_Euro', 35:'objective_combined_general', 36:'set_timeslots'})
        cols = ['set_timeslots']
    results[cols]= results [cols].round(0).astype(int)
    results.set_index('set_timeslots', inplace=True)
    results.to_csv("C:/Users/wi9632/Desktop/Result_BT1.csv", index=True,  sep =";") 
elif (solution.solver.termination_condition == TerminationCondition.infeasible):
    # Do something when model in infeasible
    print ("Result Status: Infeasible")
else:
    # Something else is wrong
    print("Solver Status: ", solution.solver.status)
```

Comment: If you have a line like this in your imports `from pyomo.environ import * `, then you should have the math functions you need for rounding. So, make sure you don't use round function from other packages (like `math` or `numpy`) or have those imports to override what pyomo is importing.

Comment: Thanks EhasnK for your comment. How can I use the math functions to round those values in Pyomo? What command do I have to use?

Comment: If you have the `from pyomo.environ import *`, then I believe the round function is already there. What I meant is to test it like that and make sure you're not rounding with `np.round` or `math.round`. This seems to be a common issue. If you do a quick search on the web, you'll see some similar questions with the same error.

Comment: Thanks EhsanK for your answer. Unfortunately `np.round(model.variable_objectiveCosts/100, 2)` leads to the following error message "TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type MonomialTermExpression which has no callable rint method". When just using `np.round(model.variable_objectiveCosts, 2)` I get a error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'"

Comment: When using `pyo.round(model.variable_objectiveCosts/100, 2)` I get the error "AttributeError: module 'pyomo.environ' has no attribute 'round'". When using `round(model.variable_objectiveCosts/100, 2)`  I get the error "TypeError: type MonomialTermExpression doesn't define __round__ method" after having imported `from pyomo.environ import *`

Comment: I suggest you post some part of your code. At least all the imports that you have, the part that you use the round function, and maybe all the variations above you tried there along with their error messages. I feel it's either some imports are overriding the others or some objects are still not defined/empty when you use it (hence, an error such as the `TypeError for NoneType and float`

Comment: Thanks EhsanK for your answer. I added the used imports. Basically I can create the dataframe with the variable `results ` and I can print it to a csv file. The only problem is that some variables like `model.variable_objectiveCosts` should be divided by 100 and rounded to 2 decimal values in the dataframe. So basically I could also just work with the pandas dataframe  `results ` and round the values there without any Pyomo specific syntax. Maybe this makes it easier?

Comment: I'm sure dealing with it in pandas will solve your problem. And about your code, I can't think of anything. If you check the [pyomo documentation](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/_/downloads/en/stable/pdf/), on page 450 there is an example of rounding objective value. But I can't tell the difference of that with what you had done.

Comment: Thanks EhsanK for your comment and effort. I really appreciate it. How can I deal with pandas such that I can round the values?

Comment: There is a lot of documentation on rounding values on the whole dataframe or just a column (series) or a single value in case you want to treat a given value differently. I'm sure you can find the appropriate command by a simple search :)

Comment: Thanks for your great help EhsanK. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to proceed is that

1. Let the Pyomo solve the problem
2. Use round(value(model.OF)) ,2)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Optimizaiton team. When I use your suggested approach in my example by using the code `round(pyo.value(model.variable_objectiveCosts/100) ,2)` I get the error "TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable". I also tried to just adjust the values in a dataframe (because at the end of the day this is what I want) by using `    df['variable_objectiveCosts'] = df['variable_objectiveCosts'/100].round(2)` but here I get also an error message telling "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'". Any idea how I can fix these errors?

Comment: share your code here to be able to provide you a better answer
before any thing try to print your answer 
can you do it in your code? 
print the value of your objective function

Comment: Thanks optimization team for your comment. I added a part of my code (my full code is quite complex and has 2000 lines) after the solve statement. You have to scroll to almost the very right for the variable `model.variable_objectiveCosts`. What I want is to print this to a file (via a pandas dataframe together with all other variables) and there it should be devided by 100 and rounded to 2 decimal values.

Comment: @PeterBe in this piece you shared in the comment,  `df['variable_objectiveCosts'] = df['variable_objectiveCosts'/100].round(2)` you're dividing by 100 in the brackets. that's why it gave you the TypeError. You need to bring it out `df['variable_objectiveCosts']/100`

Comment: I repeat my previous comment 
Please 
check if you can print the value of your objective function 
if you are successful in doing that then show me the command you used for doing so 

then I can help you to safe it as a panda dataframe or round it to 2 digits or divide it by 100

Comment: Thanks Optimization team for your comment and effort. I really appreciate it. I do not really know how to print the value of the variable to the console. However, with the given code above the value is printed in a CSV file and as stated before, this works quite well. Now I would like to have this value printed on the CSV file again but the value in the CSV file should before be divided by 100 and rounded to 2 decimal numbers.